# Merge nested JSON if keys are same in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json

How can I append new timestamps as nested json under `value_map` if the other keys in list is same?
Following is the sample list of dicts.

```
dicts = [{
    "key": "v3_CA125_2019-09-19",
    "sn": "M9257",
    "value_map": {
      "06:59:59": {
        "V_615": "1",
        "V_616": "2",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "v3_CA125_2019-09-19",
    "sn": "M9257",
    "value_map": {
      "10:59:59": {
        "V_613": "30",
        "V_614": "22"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "v3_CA125_2019-09-23",
    "sn": "M9257",
    "value_map": {
      "12:59:59": {
        "V_615": "33"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "v3_CA125_2019-09-23",
    "sn": "M9257",
    "value_map": {
      "09:59:59": {
        "V_602": "0.208984375"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I try to have an output like:

```
dicts = [{
    "key": "v3_CA125_2019-09-19",
    "sn": "M9257",
    "value_map": {
      "06:59:59": {
        "V_615": "1",
        "V_616": "2",
      },
      "10:59:59": {
        "V_613": "30",
        "V_614": "22"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "v3_CA125_2019-09-23",
    "sn": "M9257",
    "value_map": {
      "12:59:59": {
        "V_615": "33"
      },
      "09:59:59": {
        "V_602": "0.208984375"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried to append `value_map` with `OrderedDict` but couldn't reach sth so far. Any suggestions?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
for l in dicts :
    d.setdefault((l['partition_key'], l['sort_key'], l['sn']), set()).add(l['value_map'])

result = [{'partition_key': k[0], 'sort_key': k[1], 'sn':k[2], 'value_map': v.pop() if len(v) == 1 else v} for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: What exactly does *"couldn't reach sth"* mean? Give a [mcve].

Comment: 1st if you are not quite sure of what you are doing, make your code readable (if you are, make your code readable too): Use meaningful names (not letters), shorten your lines and indent, and do not start with such a long comprehension list (KISS). You can start with a simple for loop, no need for fancy stuff. 2nd, is `OrderedDict()` a requirement? 3rd. Check what `*` and `**` do in relation to unpacking, you might find it handy. You can start [here](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
key_to_index_map ={} # to know when we saw the object with a given key
desired_list = []
for elem in dicts:
  key = elem['key']
  # append if you see another object with same key
  if key in key_to_index_map:
    value_map = desired_list[key_to_index_map[key]]["value_map"]
    value_map.update(elem['value_map']);
    desired_list[key_to_index_map[key]]['value_map'] = value_map;
  else: # or simply add to the final list
    desired_list.append(elem);
    key_to_index_map[key] = len(desired_list)-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the value_map as a list while you need a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your value_map attribute needs to be an array `[]` instead of a dict `{}`

Answer (score 0):

"Merging JSON" or combining values of two dict objects in Python can be done with unpacking using the `**` operator.

In the following lines you can find a simple example in which you can observe behavior and use as needed in your problem.

```
d1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2}                                                                                                   

d2 = {"b": 3, "c": 4}                                                                                                   

d3 = {**d1, **d2}                                                                                                       

d3 # Output                                                                                                                      
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}

d4 = {**d2, **d1}                                                                                                       

d4 # Output                                                                                                                     
{'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: operative word: 'nested'